# update-rc.d and init.d dependencies

Tags: boot, rc, init.d

So I'm trying to write some init.d scripts satisfying LSB so they run appropriately at startup and shutdown. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with LSB/update-rc.d to satisfy dependencies.

```
# Required-Start: $network $local_fs hadoop-namenode hadoop-datanode zookeeper-server
# Required-Stop:  $network $local_fs hadoop-namenode hadoop-datanode zookeeper-server
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
```

however, when I run update-rc.d  defaults, it merely generates the defaults involved, with the exact same start time as the already dependencies, which breaks things horribly. Am I missing something with update-rc.d or LSB to get this configured?

In case it's relevant, this is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 13):

To make your script run later in the boot sequence, just add a sequence number, like *98* in the following command.  Then most dependencies will be satisfied.

Once, I had to use a boot script which depended on other boot scripts. This brought a lot troubles.  In the end  I used this command to solve the problem:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo update-rc.d my_script defaults 98
```

The *98* means `my_script` gets sequence number 98 at boot, it looks like it's range from 1 to 99, and most other boot scripts have smaller numbers, this ensures my script has all its dependencies ready.

BTW, to remove the old script, this can be used:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f my_old_script remove
# -f means 'force'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

This approach doesn't work anymore on some systems (Debian Squeeze for example). The number is just ignored with no explanation. The preferred method is this: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html

Look at "Required-Start:" script declaration.

Comment: Yeah I think it's because Debian added concurrent boot items with Squeeze.